# Apple "Strong Password" Suggestion breaking textfields

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, passwords

I have a sign-up flow built, but I'm having a bug where every 3 or 4 times I start to fill the sign-up sheet apple tries to make a 'stronger password'. It's breaking my text fields and making them untappable. I have a screenshot of this below. It's also guessing the wrong fields to put in a password. The middle field isn't even a secure entry field. Is there any way to disable this new password functionality?
[image]

Comment: @ManasSharma ooh okay. Thank you!

Comment: @ManasSharma Not true, it happens for me on real devices as well